# Android JUnit 4: Library not Recognized

Tags: android, junit4

I am following this tutorial to setup JUnit [Unit Testing Support](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support)

My current Android Studio version is 1.3.
When I sync my project, it seems to compile the library with no problems. When I try running my test case, I get gradle compiler error. It seems JUnit is not visible in my test class:

```
Error:Error:line (4)Gradle: error: package org.junit does not exist
Error:Error:line (6)Gradle: error: package org.junit does not exist
Error:Error:line (7)Gradle: error: package org.junit does not exist
Error:Error:line (8)Gradle: error: package org.junit does not exist
Error:Error:line (11)Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class Test
Error:Error:line (13)Gradle: error: cannot find symbol method assertFalse(boolean)
```

Here is my Test class located in src/test/java:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestCase {
    @Test
    public void testjUnit(){
        assertFalse(false);
    }
}
```

Lastly, the dependency in build.grade:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

**Edit:**

I ran the command `./gradlew testDebug --info` and received a similar error:

```
6 errors                              
:app:compileDebugJava FAILED          
:app:compileDebugJava (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.453 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
```

**Edit 2:**

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:47)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:157)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:137)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:243)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:230)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 49 more
```

Comment: Are you sure you selected the right artifact in the build variant settings?

Comment: Yes, the test artifact is set to Unit Tests

Comment: How about the file's location? `app/src/test/java/your/package/TestFile.java`

Comment: the file's location is app/src/test/java/TestCase.java

Comment: I have also tried setting it up on a new project on a different computer. Same errors. Is this happening to anyone else?

Comment: Have you tried to run the test from gradle (`./gradlew testDebug`)? You can add `--info` or  `--debug` to get more details, and might be able to see if something's not set properly.

Comment: Logged as an issue at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176086

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the java folder under test, I right clicked on the test folder and selected New > Folder > Java Folder.

When creating the java folder in this way, gradle adds the following line in the build.gradle file:

```
sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/test/java/'] } }
```

By deleting this line, the tests now run successfully.